# og:image shows only after 4 share "clicks"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've seen this is a common issue here on stack but it seems that the answer is always dependent on the specific scenario. I'm looking for a fellow coder to give me that "AHA" moment.

### Problem: Ads posted to my website do not show the og:image content when shared to facebook until the ad is shared at least 4 times

I have thought about/ tried the following things

- Checking the image size to make sure it's not large (128kb) is the norm. I compress all uploads.
- Giving the ad some time to marinate before sharing (perhaps the fb crawler takes a while to cache the page)
- I tried using the debug crawler tool on fb to see if I could reproduce the problem and I indeed could.
- I tried sharing the ad to my own page regardless of the missing image to see if the image showed up on my wall. It did not.

The image will not show up on ANY shares until someone has clicked on the share icon on an ad at least 4 times. It seems to me like it might be some latency issue on facebook's part.

What could cause og:image to only show on subsequent share clicks?

**Edit**
Here's a test ad.
https://www.jdmxchange.com/Classifieds/Details/6ae72690-14d8-4bab-b039-3a2d79923794

Comment: Adding some progress to go along with the question. 

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#precaching

Answer (score 0):

Reading https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices I found this, which might be just what you're looking for:

> 2. Use og:image:width and og:image:height Open Graph tags
>      Using these tags will specify the image to the crawler so that it can render it immediately without having to asynchronously.

This means, if you set the width and height of your og:image with tags, the image will show straight away.

**UPDATE**

Actually debugging your URL shows like this URL is redirecting to another page, and then another. Which makes me suspect the Facebook crawler is not able to access the actual OG meta tags you're using.

[image: 302 of a 302]

As a random test, I would add OG metatags to that last URL and see if Facebook uses them. But the actual solution would be to use URLs which are actually reachable to FB (no credentials necessary).

Comment: I did do this. I left a comment on my original question with the update. No hard feelings about not reading it :) Surprisingly.. This did not work for me!

Comment: Nice catch, I updated my answer hope this is useful for you to debug!

Comment: Hm. I suppose it is doing this because the ad has been deleted since then. I forgot about this debugging tool though. By the way. Thanks for that catch about the last link being a login redirect. We need to take off authorization from that method.